# Missing data not being scraped from Hansard

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, missing-data

I'm trying to scrape data from Hansard, the official verbatim record of everything spoken in the UK House of Parliament. This is the [precise link](https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Contributions?searchTerm=%22civilian%20casualties%22&startDate=01%2F01%2F1988%2000%3A00%3A00&endDate=07%2F14%2F2020%2000%3A00%3A00) I'm trying to scrape: in a nutshell, I want to scrape every "mention" container on this page and the following 50 pages after that.

But I find that when my scraper is "finished," it's only collected data on 990 containers and not the full 1010. Data on 20 containers is missing, as if it's skipping a page. When I only set the page range to (0,1), it fails to collect any values. When I set it to (0,2), it collects only the first page's values. Asking it to collect data on 52 pages does not help. I thought that this was perhaps due to the fact that I wasn't giving the URLs enough time to load, so I added some delays in the scraper's crawl. That didn't solve anything.

Can anyone provide me with any insight into what I may be missing? I'd like to make sure that my scraper is collecting all available data.

```
pages = np.arange(0, 52)

for page in pages:

     hansard_url = "https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Contributions? searchTerm=%22civilian%20casualties%22&startDate=01%2F01%2F1988%2000%3A00%3A00&endDate=07%2F14%2F2020%2000%3A00%3A00"

     full_url = hansard_url + "&page=" + str(page) + "&partial=true"
     page = get(full_url)
     html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
     mention_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_="result contribution")

     time.sleep(randint(2,10))


     for mention in mention_containers:

          topic = mention.div.span.text
          topics.append(topic)

          house = mention.find("img")["alt"]

          if house == "Lords Portcullis":
                 houses.append("House of Lords")
          elif house == "Commons Portcullis":
                 houses.append("House of Commons")
          else:
                 houses.append("N/A")

          name = mention.find('div', class_="secondaryTitle").text
          names.append(name)

          date = mention.find('div', class_="").text
          dates.append(date)

          time.sleep(randint(2,10))


 hansard_dataset = pd.DataFrame(
   {'Date': dates, 'House': houses, 'Speaker': names, 'Topic': topics})
  )

  print(hansard_dataset.info())
  print(hansard_dataset.isnull().sum())
  hansard_dataset.to_csv('hansard.csv', index=False, sep="#")
```

Any help in helping me solve this problem is appreciated.

Comment: if you use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` then adding time make no sense - it is not Selenium and it doesn't run JavaScript and it doesn't have to wait. Better save HTML in file and open in browser to see what you get. Maybe there is something different then you expect. maybe there will be some information for this problem. Or maybe first page has different URL or you has to load it without `page=0`

Comment: when I run this page in browser with `page=0` then I see `An error occurred loading the search results. Please try again later.`

Comment: standard rule: you should use `print()` to check values in variables. And this way you should check how many items you get on every page - and if some page gives less values then check this page in browser. Maybe there are different items which have different tags, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server returns on page 48 empty container, so total results are 1000 from pages 1 to 51 (inclusive):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Contributions'

params = {
    'searchTerm':'civilian casualties',
    'startDate':'01/01/1988 00:00:00',
    'endDate':'07/14/2020 00:00:00',
    'partial':'True',
    'page':1,
}

all_data = []

for page in range(1, 52):
    params['page'] = page

    print('Page {}...'.format(page))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params).content, 'html.parser')
    mention_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_="result contribution")
    if not mention_containers:
        print('Empty container!')

    for mention in mention_containers:
        topic = mention.div.span.text
        house = mention.find("img")["alt"]

        if house == "Lords Portcullis":
             house = "House of Lords"
        elif house == "Commons Portcullis":
             house = "House of Commons"
        else:
             house = "N/A"

        name = mention.find('div', class_="secondaryTitle").text
        date = mention.find('div', class_="").get_text(strip=True)

        all_data.append({'Date': date, 'House': house, 'Speaker': name, 'Topic': topic})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
...

Page 41...
Page 42...
Page 43...
Page 44...
Page 45...
Page 46...
Page 47...
Page 48...
Empty container!    # <--- here is the server error
Page 49...
Page 50...
Page 51...
                 Date             House                                            Speaker                                         Topic
0        14 July 2014    House of Lords                                     Baroness Warsi                  Gaza debate in Lords Chamber
1        3 March 2016    House of Lords                                        Lord Touhig   Armed Forces Bill debate in Grand Committee
2     2 December 2015  House of Commons                                   Mr David Cameron       ISIL in Syria debate in Commons Chamber
3        3 March 2016    House of Lords                                                      Armed Forces Bill debate in Grand Committee
4       27 April 2016    House of Lords                                                        Armed Forces Bill debate in Lords Chamber
..                ...               ...                                                ...                                           ...
995      18 June 2003    House of Lords                               Lord Craig of Radley        Defence Policy debate in Lords Chamber
996  7 September 2004    House of Lords                                           Lord Rea                  Iraq debate in Lords Chamber
997  14 February 1994    House of Lords  The Parliamentary Under-Secretary of State, Mi...             Landmines debate in Lords Chamber
998   12 January 2000  House of Commons  The Minister of State, Foreign and Commonwealt...  Serbia And Kosovo debate in Westminster Hall
999  26 February 2003    House of Lords                                           Lord Rea                  Iraq debate in Lords Chamber

[1000 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, you're right, this really works in finding server errors! But I have one question: when I go to page 48 manually, I see that the containers aren't empty. Does that just mean the scraper is failing to pick up these containers, and I should just enter those values manually? Sorry if this is a stupid question, all help is appreciated!

Comment: For reference: https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Contributions?endDate=2020-07-14&partial=true&searchTerm=%22civilian+casualties%22&startDate=1988-01-01&page=48

Comment: @xrichervis When you go manually, the server error is on page 41: https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Contributions?endDate=2020-07-14&partial=true&searchTerm=%22civilian+casualties%22&startDate=1988-01-01&page=41  I think the results are sorted differently then.

Comment: Yeah I noticed this after I commented. Bizarre. I don't think there's anything I can do about these missing values. Thanks again for all your help Andrej!